# Krull's principal ideal theorem

Tags: commutative-algebra, proof-explanation

I have following question about a step in the proof of Krull's principal ideal theorem here:
https://commalg.subwiki.org/wiki/Krull%27s_principal_ideal_theorem

If the link doesn't work:
[image]

Why we can replace $R$ by it's localisation $R_p$ without loss of generality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prime ideals of $R_p$ correspond to the prime ideals of $R$ that are
contained in $p$. The height of $p$ as a prime ideal in $R$ is the same
as $pR_p$ as an ideal of $R_p$, i.e., the Krull dimension of $R_p$.
So we need to show that $R_p$ has Krull dimension 1.

Also $p$ is a minimal prime in $R$ containing $x$. So $pR_p$ contains $x/1$
in $R_p$. Any other prime in $R_p$ containing $x/1$ is $qR_p$
where $q\subset p$ is a prime in $p$. Then $x/1\in qR_p$ means $xs\in q$
where $s\notin q$, so $x\in q$ as $q$ is prime. This gives a contradiction:
$pR_p$ is the only prime ideal in $R_p$ with $x/1$ as an element.